# Scrolling to the bottom of 500 emails

Tags: ipad, email, macos

Is there an easy way to scroll up and down in the left hand pane in e-mail?
I have my ipad set to display 500 emails and its a pain to get from an email at the bottom of the list to one back at the top again.
There is an indicator bar that goes up and down as you scroll but you don't seem to be able to drag it. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

A fast way to get back to the top from anywhere in the list is to tap the status bar above the list. This works in many places throughout iOS, like Safari, Notes, etc.

The only fast way to the bottom, though, is to swipe as fast as you can!

Comment: This is true. iOS is designed with "inertia" scrolling. While there is no way to instantly get to the bottom of a page like one can do to the top, scrolling (or better, "flicking") quickly will allow you to reach your destination speedily.

Answer (score 1):

To get back to the top quickly, you can filter your email by unread. This takes you to the top of your unread emails. Tap/open on your first email then go back tap again to unfilter.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the bottom of your emails quickly.
Type ‘bottom’ into search box.Press search. Then when you start scrolling, the side bar is much bigger and scrolls down in seconds.
Beverly

Answer (score -1):

You may type top to go to the start or bottom to go to the bottom. You may even type the month or year of the transaction.

Comment: Where does one type the named commands?

Answer (score -2):

Just tap above the where inbox is written and you will be taken to the top

Comment: Hows does this differ or improve on the other answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/92700/237